# Autolayout subview vertically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, xcode6

[image]

I'm trying to set autolayout for a view controller with subview align vertically as you can see in the pic. The result I want is when ever screen size change, each subview will scale but preserve it aspect ratio and align center, except the last one will need to have enough space for textfield and button inside it

What I have tried so far:

- Set aspect ratio required constraint for each subview except the last
  one
- Set vertical spacing high constraint between each subview
- Set vertical spacing to top border required constraint for first
  subview
- Set leading and trailing space low constraint for each subview
- Set vertical spacing to bottom border required constraint for last
  subview

Despite what I tried, when screen size change, only first and last subview get scale (bigger or smaller), but I want all of them scale accordingly as describe above. Which constraint should I set to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all of them to scale proportionally you would need to add constraints to hold relation between their sizes. Specifying that second rect has half of the first height and so on.